# form submitted in iframes failing on some computers

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, iframe

Using a function to submit 2 forms in seperate iframes and then submit a form on parent page.
The (strange problem is) my method seems to work ok on one computer on others it only submits the form on the parent page. The browsers are the same (firefox, same version).
I wonder why is this happening and how to fix this. Here is the html and function

```
   <form id="projects" method="post">
    ...
    <input type="submit" class="button-primary" value="" >
    </form>
    <iframe id="lean">...<form method="post"><input type="submit" class="button-primary" value="submit" ></form></iframe>
    <iframe id="lean2">...<form method="post"><input type="submit" class="button-primary" value="submit" ></form></iframe>
    <button if="herewego">Submit all</button>
```

js

```
$(window).load(function(){
$('#herewego').click(function(){
if ($("#lean").contents().find("#_dtm_first_name").val().length >= 1){
$("#lean").contents().find('.button-primary').click();}
if ($("#lean2").contents().find("#_dtm_first_name").val().length >= 1){
$("#lean2").contents().find('.button-primary').click();}
$('#projects').find('.button-primary').click();
});
```

The form in the parent page redirects.
my theory is that on overloaded broswers there is enough time to submit the forms inside the iframes and on less loaded browsers it happens so fast only the form in the parent gets submitted. Is this the case and if so how should i restructure my js so both iframes forms get submitted before the parent page form?

Answer (score 1):

Javascript is asynchronous so if you want to submit the iframe forms first, you need to rely on callback functions. It's interesting though that JQuery's click() function doesn't seem to have a callback mechanism so you would need to find some other "flag" as a reference, e.g., how about using the iframe forms submit event? You could make sure that the parent form only gets submitted after the other two onSubmit() functions are called (You could use a counter or something..).

Another, perhaps over-engineered, way of solving this problem would be by using JQuery's `$.when`, I've used this before to guarantee synchronized events involving Ajax calls, not 100% sure if that would work in your case, but it is a cool technique :)

```
var deferreds = getSomeDeferredStuff();

        $.when.apply($,deferreds).done(
            function() {
                //Only execute this block after the iframe forms are submitted
                console.log('Success!');

                submitParentForm();

            }).fail(function() {
                // Oh noes, something went wrong :(
                console.log('The process failed');          
            }
        );

function getSomeDeferredStuff() {
    var deferreds = [];

    deferreds.push(submitIframeForm1());
    deferreds.push(submitIframeForm2());

    return deferreds;
}
```